# Suspending serial queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Today i've tried following code:

```
- (void)suspendTest {
    dispatch_queue_attr_t attr = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT, QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0);
    dispatch_queue_t suspendableQueue = dispatch_queue_create("test", attr);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
        dispatch_async(suspendableQueue, ^{
            NSLog(@"%d", i);
        });
        if (i == 5000) {
            dispatch_suspend(suspendableQueue);
        }
    }
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(6 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Show must go on!");
        dispatch_resume(suspendableQueue);
    });
}
```

The code starts 10001 tasks, but it should suspend the queue from running new tasks halfway for resuming in 6 seconds. And this code *works as expected* - 5000 tasks executes, then queue stops, and after 6 seconds it resumes. 
But if i use a serial queue instead of concurrent queue, the behaviour is not clear for me.

```
dispatch_queue_attr_t attr = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0);
```

In this case a random number of tasks manage to execute before suspending, but often this number is close to zero (suspending happens before any tasks).
The question is - Why does suspending work differently for serial and concurrent queue and how to suspend serial queue properly?

Comment: The code you posted won't compile. Your `if (i == 5000) {` line is after the `for` loop.

Comment: My fault, i just reproduced it by memory. Let me fix it

Comment: Okay, so this is one of those questions where you don't paste your real code into the browser? I can't get behind that.

Comment: @matt I've written it from a picture i did in my office. Just a typo :)

Comment: Let me ask you this: why do you expect _anything_? There is no guarantee about when the queue will start, especially, given that it is `QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND`. So aren't you just saying that the serial queue never got started? Why is this a surprise, since there are no rules about it? And _especially_ since you are hogging the main queue, which might make the background queue even less willing to get started? The actual thread management, after all, is not up to us; that is the _point_ of GCD.

Comment: As far as i know, there is a rule that any block have already been queued should be executed, and any block after suspending should wait for resuming.

Comment: "there is a rule that any block have already been queued should be executed" And eventually it _is_ executed. But it isn't going to be executed after suspension on the serial queue because we cannot even _start_, let alone execute. That is what serial _means_.

Comment: Maybe you were thinking of a _barrier_? `suspend` is not the same as a barrier. Put a barrier after the 5000th task and things will behave as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per its name, the serial queue performs the tasks in series, i.e., only starting on the next one after the previous one has been completed. The priority class is background, so it may not even have started on the first task by the time the current queue reaches the 5000th task and suspends the queue.

From the documentation of `dispatch_suspend`:

> The suspension occurs after completion of any blocks running at the time of the call.

i.e., nowhere does it promise that asynchronously dispatched tasks on the queue would finish, only that any *currently running* task (block) will not be suspended part-way through. On a serial queue at most one task can be "currently running", whereas on a concurrent queue there is no specified upper limit. **edit:** And according to your test with a million tasks, it seems the concurrent queue maintains the conceptual abstraction that it is "completely concurrent", and thus considers all of them "currently running" even if they actually aren't.

To suspend it after the 5000th task, you could trigger this from the 5000th task itself. (Then you probably also want to start the resume-timer from the time it is suspended, otherwise it is theoretically possible it will never resume if the resume happened before it was suspended.)

Comment: So why does the concurrent queue runs like clockwork with the same priority?

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev It doesn't really matter; the API specifies what you can expect and you can't expect the serial queue to work the way you want. My guess is that since it is concurrent, it treats all dispatched tasks as "currently running" and lets them complete, whereas a serial queue only considers at most one task "currently running".

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev It would also be an interesting experiment if you were to increase both the number and length of the tasks with the concurrent queue. Does it still work if you dispatch 50,000 and each does more work?

Comment: I did it! I tested with a million, It took for about 2 minutes and concurrent queue executes exactly 500000 tasks before suspending

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev Interesting, I guess the queue then internally considers all of those tasks as "currently running" to maintain the abstraction (i.e., keeps you from having to think about the actual number of threads if your intent is to have all of those tasks in parallel).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are confusing `suspend` with `barrier`. `suspend` stops the queue dead *now*. `barrier` stops when everything in the queue before the barrier has executed. So if you put a barrier after the 5000th task, 5000 tasks will execute before we pause at the barrier on the serial queue.

Comment: thank you for suggestion. I'm aware of `barrier`s, but the question is not related to solution. I'm interested in how it works, and what it means "already running tasks" in terms of suspending and concurrent queue. Anyway your effort is appreciated.